# Spark Structured Streaming - ABRiS - calls to schema registry with http instead of https

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, confluent-schema-registry

I am using the ABRiS library (https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS) with schema registry to read data from Kafka and deserialize them. This works well if I have a Confluent schema registry that requires just http call, but breaks when I have an https one. I am unable to force ABRis to make a https call.

My code

```
val schemaRegistry: String = "https://MY_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL:443"

val registryConfig = Map(
AbrisConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL -> schemaRegistry,
"basic.auth.credentials.source" -> "USER_INFO",
"basic.auth.user.info" -> s"$user:$pass",
"schema.registry.ssl.enabled" -> "true",
"ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm" -> "",
"schema.registry.ssl.truststore.type" -> "sth",
"schema.registry.ssl.keystore.type" -> "sth",
"schema.registry.ssl.truststore.location" -> "sth",
"schema.registry.ssl.truststore.password" -> "sth",
"schema.registry.ssl.keystore.location" -> "sth",
"schema.registry.ssl.keystore.password" -> "sth"
)

val abrisConfig = AbrisConfig
.fromConfluentAvro
.downloadReaderSchemaByLatestVersion
.andTopicNameStrategy(topic)
.usingSchemaRegistry(registryConfig)

val deserializedStream = df.select(
from_avro(col("value"), abrisConfig) as "data",
col("topic"),
col("timestamp") as "kafka_timestamp"
)

deserializedStream
.writeStream
.format("console") ...
```

produces

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 15) (10.61.26.6 executor 1): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Malformed record detected.

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Not able to download writer schema

Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path:

http://MY_SCHEMA_REGISTRY+URL/schemas/ids/102?fetchMaxId=false&subject=

; error code: 404
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:314)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:384)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:853)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:826)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:311)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaBySubjectAndId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:433)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaById(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:409)
at za.co.absa.abris.avro.registry.AbstractConfluentRegistryClient.getById(AbstractConfluentRegistryClient.scala:44)
at za.co.absa.abris.avro.read.confluent.SchemaManager.getSchemaById(SchemaManager.scala:49)
at za.co.absa.abris.avro.sql.AvroDataToCatalyst.$anonfun$downloadWriterSchema$1(AvroDataToCatalyst.scala:160)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
at za.co.absa.abris.avro.sql.AvroDataToCatalyst.downloadWriterSchema(AvroDataToCatalyst.scala:160)
```

notice the http:// in calling the schema registry. How can I force abris to use https?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: See this? https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS/issues/208

Comment: thanks, but that does not say anything about https?

Comment: You mean other than the literal issue text? I looked at the source code, and it doesn't hard code `http` anywhere, and seems to always use the url config provided... If you're running the registry behind a proxy, then you might experience different behavior

Comment: yes, the name of the issue fits, but it just links to documentation that does not mention anything about how to fix this. If you see anything in the linked docs that would make it use https, I will be glad for the help. I am not running it behind a proxy. Thanks for your time btw.

Comment: Right. As mentioned in your own github issue, the url is used as-is, so it shouldn't be removing ssl from itself. Are you using more than one schema registry? Do they all have `listeners` setting defined with HTTPS? If you don't have a registry cluster, there's no reason for the stacktrace to include `RestService.sendHttpRequest` as the one master registry would already have information you need.

Comment: You could update your log4j config to debug level and you'd see this line https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/client/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/client/rest/RestService.java#L275